# Different ways to pass variables in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I'm rather new to MS Build and have been reviewing many of the built in target files that ship with Visual Studio. I have seen variables passed a few different ways and am not quite sure of the differences between these:

```
$(...)
@(...)
%(...)
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

- `$(...)`is used to access `Property` value (More info on [Property element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164288.aspx))

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Message Text="Configuration = $(Configuration)"/>
  ```
- `@(...)` is used to access `Item` value (More info on [Item element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164283.aspx))

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Data"/>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="References = @(Reference)"/>
  ```
- `%(...)` is used to acces `Item Metadata` value (More info on [Item Metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164284.aspx)). It's also used to do [batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx).

  ```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Account\ChangePassword.aspx.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ChangePassword.aspx</DependentUpon>
      <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
    <Compile/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Text="Element @(Compile) of subtype %(SubType) and depend of %(DependentUpon)"/>
  ```

Answer (score 24):

[Dollar - $(MyProp):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) Allows you to reference values specified within PropertyGroups.

[At Sign - @(CodeFile):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171454.aspx) Allows you to reference lists of items specified within ItemGroups.

[Percent - %(CodeFile.BatchNum):](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171474.aspx) Allows you to reference batched ItemGroup values using metadata. This is a bit more complicated, so definitely review the documentation for more info.

Take a look at each link for more detailed info on how these are used.  Good luck -- hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of extension on the % (item metadata), there is also the Well-known item metadata:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-well-known-item-metadata?view=vs-2017

E.g. ModifiedTime:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <IntermediateAssembly Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)"/>
  </ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile>%(IntermediateAssembly.ModifiedTime)</_AssemblyTimestampBeforeCompile>
</PropertyGroup>
```